# Does Amazon EC2 Elastic IP ever change?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

If I reserve a Elastic IP to my Amazon EC2 instance, can I have the same IP address as long as I pay for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you get it until you release it.

The elastic part means that you can elastically associate it to any of your ec2 instances, you can switch between instances as much as it pleases you.

And you don't actually pay for it while it's associated to a running instance.